# What's wrong with this Javascript for "Get URL and Title"?

Tags: javascript, twitter, bookmarklet

```
javascript:(
    function(){
        window.twttr = window.twttr || {};
        var D = 550,
        A = 450,
        C = screen.height,
        B = screen.width,
        H = Math.round((B/2)-(D/2)),
        G = 0,
        F = document,
        E;

        if (C > A) {
           G = Math.round((C/2) - (A/2))
        }

        window.twttr.shareWin = window.open(
            'http://twitter.com/share?text=test+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(d.title)','','left='+H+',top='+G+',width='+D+',height='+A+',personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
        E = F.createElement('script');
        F.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(E)
    }());
```

This is the code, it is supposed to open the twitter tweet window , and inside it must be filled with the url of the page. however , when used as a button in google chrome , it does nothing , and by removing the "?text=" from the javascript , I got a blank tweet page which isn't what I want.
so how can fix it so it writes down the url and title? like this:
Title - Url

the url code of the Text is "?text="

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing apostrophe:

```
'http://twitter.com/share?text=test'
```

entire snippet with fix:

```
javascript:(function(){window.twttr=window.twttr||{};var D=550,A=450,C=screen.height,B=screen.width,H=Math.round((B/2)-(D/2)),G=0,F=document,E;if(C>A){G=Math.round((C/2)-(A/2))}window.twttr.shareWin=window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=test'+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(d.title)','','left='+H+',top='+G+',width='+D+',height='+A+',personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');E=F.createElement('script');F.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(E)}());
```

pretty code:

```
javascript:(
    function(){
        window.twttr = window.twttr || {};
        var D = 550,
        A = 450,
        C = screen.height,
        B = screen.width,
        H = Math.round((B/2)-(D/2)),
        G = 0,
        F = document,
        E;

        if (C > A) {
           G = Math.round((C/2) - (A/2))
        }

        window.twttr.shareWin = window.open(
            'http://twitter.com/share?text=test'+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(d.title)','','left='+H+',top='+G+',width='+D+',height='+A+',personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
        E = F.createElement('script');
        F.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(E)
    }());
```

Comment: didn't notice, I was also missing +'?' , since "?" is the variable that tells it what to write inside.